# If $|f| \leq A + B|z|^k$ then $f$ is polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire function such that $|f(z)|\leq A+B|z|^k$ for all $z$, where $A$, $B$, $k$ are positive numbers.

Prove that $f$ is polynomial.

Comment: By "full" I'm guessing you mean ["entire"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function). Please consider adding some remarks on what you've tried for this problem.

Comment: Hint: show that the n'th derivatives of $f$ begin to vanish at a certain point, using Cauchy's theorem

Answer (score 4):

Since $f(z)$ is entire, from Cauchy integral formula, we have $$f^{(n)}(0) = \dfrac{n!}{2 \pi i}\oint_{C_r} \dfrac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}} dz$$
On $C_r$, the integrand is bounded by $$\left \vert \dfrac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}} \right \vert \leq \dfrac{A}{\left \vert z^{n+1} \right \vert} + \dfrac{B}{\left \vert z^{n+1-k} \right \vert} = \dfrac{A}{r^{n+1}} + \dfrac{B}{r^{n+1-k}}$$ Now argue out why $f^{(n)}(0) = 0$ for $n > k$ by letting $r \to \infty$ and looking at what happens to the integral.

Comment: Note that this is nothing but a minor refinement of the usual proof of [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(complex_analysis))

Comment: @DylanMoreland Ah Yes. I have changed it now.

Comment: Why is it that $f(z)\leq \frac{A}{z^{n+1}} + \frac{B}{z^{n+1-k}}$?. Hypothesis?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: start with $f(z)/z^k$ (assuming $k$ is an integer) and subtract the principal part of the pole at $0$.  What could be left?

Answer (score 0):

Show that $f$ has (at worst) a pole at infinity.